# Conditional single.php statement not recognizing conditionals

Tags: conditional-tags, single

I have tried every possible way of making this conditional work and it's skipping the in_category conditionals and going to the last option. This is my code in single.php:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
if (in_category('Autos')) {
    get_template_part("single-autos.php");
} else if (in_category('Advertising')) {
    get_template_part("single-ads.php");
} else {
    get_template_part("single-post.php");
}
```

I have conditionals all over this theme that work by calling the `in_category` for those two categories, but no matter what I do, this conditional always reverts to the single-post.php layout. single-autos.php and single-ads.php do exist in the theme.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edited to add the code from single-autos.php:

```
 get_header();
<div id="blogcontent" class="auto">

     if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

          get_template_part( 'loop' );

     comments_template(); 

    <div id="singlepagination">
        <div class="newer">< next_post_link(); > </div>
        <div class="older">< previous_post_link(); > </div>
    </div>

     endwhile; else: 

        <h2>Thank you for pushing the self-destruct button. This ship will self destruct in ten seconds.</h2>

 endif; 


</div><!--/content-->
 get_sidebar(); 
 get_footer();
```

Comment: Try to `echo` something like `A/B/C` inside the `if/elseif/else` to see that it's not a typo or similar.

Comment: Are you using the conditionals in a standard loop? I suspect that's the issue because usually you retrieve the global $post object rather than setting $post within the template.

Comment: **Where** - i.e. in *what template file* - is this code?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear - I said this in my first paragraph... This is in single.php :)

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant to your question, but your markup has syntax errors; namely, you're not closing/opening PHP tags properly between PHP output and HTML output.

Comment: Oh, LOL. someone edited my original code and took those out... so I did too. :)

Comment: I've added the full code into pastebin [single.php](http://pastebin.com/idSi4qxf) and [single-autos.php](http://pastebin.com/97QKJMae). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first suspicion that something is amiss is this:

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
```

You shouldn't need to do this. Anywhere that the query conditionals are already setup, the conditionals will *assume* the current Post ID. So, that suggests a couple things:

1. The specified categories don't actually exist. I will assume this *not* to be true, since you indicate that you use this same code successfully elsewhere in the Theme.
2. You're calling this code somewhere that the current query/post isn't actually *set*. For example, you might be calling this code in the context of an archive index page, or a search page, etc. *outside* the Loop. The odd thing here is that your title indicates that you're calling this code in `single.php`.

Can you do two things:

1. Post your entire `single.php` code, so we can see the conditional code in context?
2. Try replacing `$post = $wp_query->post;` with `global $post;`

#### Edit

> What's posted above is the entire single.php

What's being returned by the `$post` object? What do you get on a `var_dump( $post );` after you globalize it?

Also, probably not related to your problem (the query is set at `wp`, so query conditionals should be available at `template_redirect`, which is where `single.php` gets loaded), but I would suggest putting your `get_header()`, `get_sidebar()`, and `get_footer()` calls in `single.php`, and trim `single-auto.php`, etc. down to their actual *content*.

Comment: What's posted above is the entire single.php:           `<?php
global $post;
if (in_category('Autos')) {
 get_template_part("single-autos.php");
} else if (in_category('Advertising')) {
 get_template_part("single-ads.php");
} else {
 get_template_part("single-post.php");
}
?>`

Comment: At the moment single-autos.php, single-ads.php and single-post.php are exactly the same except for one class to change the background and colours. I'm posting in the original question, as there's not enough room here...

Comment: See updated answer. Are you getting anything returned by the globalized `$post` object?

Comment: I don't think so... I took it out completely. I was using a tutorial I found [here](http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2005/09/22/creating-multiple-single-posts-for-different-categories/) which I realize is insanely old, but worked the last time I used it.

Comment: But did you *test* it? If you're not getting anything returned from the `$post` object, then that observation is probably directly related to your problem.